# Re-sizing Text According to Re-sized Container

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, visual-studio-2012

Assume I have a re-sizable part in UI that is a standard WPF container control (in this case a Canvas) and I put some text on this Canvas. How can I re-size my text according to rendered size of my Canvas?

Comment: if I understood you correclty, you want to update `FontSize` to fit in some `Canvas`. am I right?

Comment: Yes and I want to have a min-fontsize too.

Answer (score 1):

Viewbox will stretch a TextBlock

[How to: Apply Stretch Properties to the Contents of a Viewbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752301%28v=vs.100%29)

```
<Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="vb1" Stretch="Fill" >
    <TextBlock Text="tulip_farm.jpg"/>
</Viewbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply link a method to the container resize event, that will resize the text as well (this way they are always in sync), i would offer an example but since you did not post an example, i think you undetrstand what i mean.